# ZipArchive::CREATE not working

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am trying to test the ZipArchive function within my application and for some reason I'm not getting anything.

**See my vardump**

```
object(ZipArchive)#1 (5) { ["status"]=> int(0) ["statusSys"]=> int(0)
 ["numFiles"]=> int(0) ["filename"]=> string(31) 
"E:\xampp\htdocs\test\zipfile.zip" ["comment"]=> string(0) "" }
```

**My PHP**

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('zipfile.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

if($zip === TRUE){

} else {
    var_dump($zip);
}
```

When checking the destination I am not getting any zip file, I have also checked to see if the extension is activated and I can confirm it is.

Comment: The zip file is written on the call to `close()`, not on the call to `open()`.... as you're not calling `close()`, it's never actually written

Comment: Thank you for the reply @MarkBaker am I right in saying I have to change the open() to save()? if so I've just tried this and it get **all to undefined method ZipArchive::save() **

Comment: You have to close it. Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Comment: No, you still need to do the `open()`..... but no file is actually written to disk until you do the `close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it appeared that everything was ok but the file was not generated until I added some content.

```
<?php
    $zf=__DIR__ . '\zipfile.zip';

    /* To create a simple zip archive */
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open( $zf, ZipArchive::CREATE );

    if( $res === TRUE ){
        $zip->addFromString('test.txt', 'This is some dummy data - without one file this seems to fail');
        $zip->close();
    } else {
        var_dump( $zip );
    }


    /* One approach to zip a directory */       
    $dir=__DIR__;
    $files=glob( $dir . '\*.*' );

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open( $zf, ZipArchive::CREATE );
    if( $res===true ){
        foreach( $files as $file )  $zip->addFile( $file, basename( $file ) );
        $zip->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @ramraider That's exactly what I needed, just out of interest would you know what to add to that code to scan a directly and zip up the directory contents?

Comment: @Wolrab - look to use the [addGlob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addglob.php) or [addPattern()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addpattern.php) methods to do a whole directory or set of files in a single call

Comment: @MarkBaker - cool, didn't know about those methods! These do not appear in the manual for the version of PHP I have... good to know